# Can I participate if my language of choice does not have functions?

Tags: discussion

If my language of choice does not have a concept of functions, and the challenge requires a function, can I submit an entire program instead?

Comment: I assume the program would read from STDIN, rather than having the input in a variable?

Comment: @xnor I expanded on the [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4793/18487) answer to address your comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the language doesn't have anything called a function, but has a close equivalent, you can submit that instead. I'm thinking of Golfscript and relatives' code blocks, but I'm sure many languages have them.

Close equivalents should have the option of taking an input and giving an output, though these do not need to be used in the code itself.

If no construct in the language can take an input and give an output, then the language (unfortunately) cannot be used.

Comment: @Rainbolt If you feel that something is missing in the answer, perhaps you could include an example. From my perspective this answer is good enough for practical purposes.

Comment: Thanks for making the answer complete.

Comment: `sed` really has no concept of functions, though it does allow input/output.  Are these two answers invalid? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/45636/11259 http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/3928/11259

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If the challenge requires functions, submitting an entire program is fine if and only if your language of choice does not have functions.

You should still follow all of the other rules for the challenge. If input is provided via STDIN, you must accept input via STDIN. If input is provided via arguments, your program must accept arguments.

Comment: If the question requires you to answer with a function, why would it specify how the program gets input? Unless I'm misunderstanding, it would always be "function arguments" which are very different from "stdin" or "command line arguments". That's my only problem with this answer.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail I don't like this answer either. That said, obviously a program cannot take "function arguments", so a compromise would have to be made.